# How can I ensure varnish always has a child process running?

Tags: varnish

Now and again I encounter a problem on a varnish box which results in varnish's child process dying.  It usually looks something along the lines of:

```
Feb 26 17:09:45 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (32289) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 26 17:09:55 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (32289) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 26 17:10:00 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (32289) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 26 17:10:00 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (32289) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 26 17:10:00 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (32289) died signal=3
Feb 26 17:10:00 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child cleanup complete
Feb 26 17:10:00 webstar varnishd[9775]: child (30475) Started
Feb 26 17:10:10 webstar varnishd[9775]: Pushing vcls failed:#012CLI communication error (hdr)
Feb 26 17:10:10 webstar varnishd[9775]: Stopping Child
Feb 26 17:10:10 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (30475) said Child starts
Feb 26 17:10:27 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (30475) said Child dies
Feb 26 17:10:28 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child (30475) died status=1
Feb 26 17:10:28 webstar varnishd[9775]: Child cleanup complete
```

A restart of the varnish service usually fixes it and when I dig into the cause it's generally being constrained on one resource or another.

That's all as expected, but it does mean that between the child process being killed and me manually resolving the issue, that varnish box isn't able to serve any traffic.  What can I do to make a new child spawn automatically when the old one dies?  Is it possible to configure the parent varnish process to handle this itself, or is the only option to get something external (eg puppet or chef) to do a restart when this problem occurs?

Comment: I've just come across the param `auto_restart` which sounds exactly what I need.  However, it's already set to "on" (the default), but doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: The `auto_restart` feature is working according to your logs. It seems that something stopping the process to be restarted. Try to make a further investigation before you restart manually. There must be something in the connection between the Varnish processes.

Comment: I normally try to do some investigation before a manual restart, but I'm running out of things I know to investigate.
Having said that, I've increased the `cli_timeout` param and haven't encountered the issue in over a week...